# How do you assign value to char[] in heap?

Tags: c++, c

I got a _CrtIsValidHeapPointer error with my code. And I finally find out what caused the trouble.
I use the example below to illustrate it:

```
char* c=(char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
//cout<<&c<<endl;
c="hello world";
//cout<<&c<<endl;  //if you uncomment the 2 clauses,you'll see the address is the same
                                  //which means the string literal is in the heap
cout<<c<<endl;
free(c);
```

1) It seemed that spaces used by string literals can't be freed? Why?

2)What't the method do you use to assign valee to array of char?
ps: I use `sprintf(c,"hello world");` that works fine. But any better way?

---

After read the answers. I realize that I misunderstand the meaning of &c.
I should use `printf("%p\n",c);` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to correctly assign a new String value in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131319/how-to-correctly-assign-a-new-string-value-in-c)

Comment: @JensGustedt :They do have some connections and similarities. But I don't think it's a duplicate.  Thanks for your link anyway, it's useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [`strcpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy), or a safer version `strncpy`. Note that with `strncpy`, you have to NUL-terminate the string yourself in case there was not enough space.

Examples:

```
char *some_other_string = ...;
int len = strlen(some_other_string);
char *c = malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(*c));
if (c == NULL)
    // handle error

strcpy(c, some_other_string);

free(c);
```

Note that in this case, we know there is enough space in `c`, so we can use `strcpy`. If we don't know, you can cut the string up to where you can handle it:

```
char *some_other_string = ...;
char *c = malloc((MAX_LEN + 1) * sizeof(*c));
if (c == NULL)
    // handle error

strncpy(c, some_other_string, MAX_LEN);
c[MAX_LEN] = '\0';

free(c);
```

Note that in the case of `strncpy`, if there is not enough space, the string is not NUL-terminated and you have to do it manually.

---

Side note:

`&c` is the address of variable `c`. It has nothing to do with its contents, so no matter what you do with `c`, `&c` will not change.

Comment: You meant `c[MAX_LEN - 1]` instead of `c[MAX_LEN]`.

Comment: @ouah, no I meant to allocate `MAX_LEN + 1` memory for `c`, but thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Shahbaz: I think this would be correct, `c[MAX_LEN + 1] = '\0';` because we want to put endline to end of the variable space.

Comment: @reza, in C, when you take an array of size `n`, you have access to indices 0 to `n-1`. Since I allocated `MAX_LEN + 1` elements, the last element I can legally access is at index `MAX_LEN`.

Answer (score 7):

You should copy the string using `strcpy`.

The assignment `c="hello world"` doesn't copy the contents of the string, but assigns the address of the string literal to the pointer c. When you call `free(c)` afterwards, the pointer is not a valid heap address any more.

> //if you uncomment the 2 clauses,you'll see the address is the same

What you see is not the *value* of pointer `c`, but the *address* of the pointer, which is obviously the same.

Answer (score 3):

```
c = "hello world";
```

You are modidying the `c` pointer to the pointer to the `"hello world"` string literal. This does not copy the string but just modify the `c` pointer. You have to use the `strcpy` function to copy a string in an array of `char`.

```
strcpy(c, "hello world");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the C++ part of the language, this is all handled by the `std::string` in the C++ standard library.

```
std::string c = "hello world"; 
cout << c << endl;
```

Done!

You don't have to manage anything manually.