# JSON data in Web_custom_request- Vugen

Tags: json, loadrunner

LR script throws warning and fails for the JSON Response.

Below is the script

char *request_json_base;

char *request_json;

web_add_header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

```
request_json_base=  "{\"GLDefaultId\":0,\"ProjectId\":{ContactProjectId},\"CoaMainId\":10,\"UserId\":{UserId},\"Notes\":\"\",\"PRO_GLDefaultValue\":[{\"GLDefaultValueId\":0,\"GLDefaultId\":0,\"SegmentId\":16,\"Alias\":\"ACT\",\"SegmentType\":\"DETAIL\",\"FunctionTypeId\":0,\"Value\":\"&&&\",\"Mask\":\"&&&\",\"IsRequired\":true,\"LastModified\":null,\"IsCoaRequired\":true},{\"GLDefaultValueId\":0,\"GLDefaultId\":0,\"SegmentId\":17,\"Alias\":\"ST\",\"SegmentType\":\"SET\",\"FunctionTypeId\":0,\"Value\":\"&&\",\"Mask\":\"&&\",\"IsRequired\":false,\"LastModified\":null,\"IsCoaRequired\":false}]}",
```

request_json = lr_eval_string(request_json_base);

lr_save_string(request_json, "REQUEST_JSON_PARAM");

```
web_custom_request("PRO_GLDefault",
    "URL=https://{URL}/PayrollWebApi/V1/PRO_GLDefault?userId={UserId}",
    "Method=POST",
    "TargetFrame=",
    "Resource=0",
    "RecContentType=application/json",
    "Referer=",
    "Snapshot=t299.inf",
    "Mode=HTML",
    "EncType=application/json",
    "Body={REQUEST_JSON_PARAM}",
LAST);
```

**Below is  Replay Log :**

Action3_SUNP_ProjectSetup_RatesandSetupInfo.c(81): Warning: The string '"GLDefaultValueId":0,"GLDefaultId":0,"SegmentId":16,"Alias":"ACT","SegmentType":"DETAIL","FunctionTypeId":0,"Value":"&&&","Mask":"&&&","IsRequired":true,"LastModified":null,"IsCoaRequired":true' ***with parameter delimiters is not a parameter.***

Action3_SUNP_ProjectSetup_RatesandSetupInfo.c(81): Warning: The string '"GLDefaultValueId":0,"GLDefaultId":0,"SegmentId":17,"Alias":"ST","SegmentType":"SET","FunctionTypeId":0,"Value":"&&","Mask":"&&","IsRequired":false,"LastModified":null,"IsCoaRequired":false' ***with parameter delimiters is not a parameter.***

Action3_SUNP_ProjectSetup_RatesandSetupInfo.c(83): Notify: Saving Parameter "REQUEST_JSON_PARAM = {"GLDefaultId":0,"ProjectId":1810,"CoaMainId":10,"UserId":67,"Notes":"","PRO_GLDefaultValue":[{"GLDefaultValueId":0,"GLDefaultId":0,"SegmentId":16,"Alias":"ACT","SegmentType":"DETAIL","FunctionTypeId":0,"Value":"&&&","Mask":"&&&","IsRequired":true,"LastModified":null,"IsCoaRequired":true},{"GLDefaultValueId":0,"GLDefaultId":0,"SegmentId":17,"Alias":"ST","SegmentType":"SET","FunctionTypeId":0,"Value":"&&","Mask":"&&","IsRequired":false,"LastModified":null,"IsCoaRequired":false}]}".

**Action3_SUNP_ProjectSetup_RatesandSetupInfo.c(85):     {"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred."}**

**Below is Body of Original Request call:**

"Body={\"GLDefaultId\":0,\"ProjectId\":{ContactProjectId},\"CoaMainId\":10,\"UserId\":{UserId},\"Notes\":\"\",\"PRO_GLDefaultValue\":[{\"GLDefaultValueId\":0,\"GLDefaultId\":0,\"SegmentId\":16,\"Alias\":\"ACT\",\"SegmentType\":\"DETAIL\",\"FunctionTypeId\":0,\"Value\":\"&&&\",\"Mask\":\"&&&\",\"IsRequired\":true,\"LastModified\":null,\"IsCoaRequired\":true},{\"GLDefaultValueId\":0,\"GLDefaultId\":0,\"SegmentId\":17,\"Alias\":\"ST\",\"SegmentType\":\"SET\",\"FunctionTypeId\":0,\"Value\":\"&&\",\"Mask\":\"&&\",\"IsRequired\":false,\"LastModified\":null,\"IsCoaRequired\":false}]}",
        LAST);

**Below is the Successful Response during the recording:**

***Request*** : 
{
    "GLDefaultId": 0,
    "ProjectId": 1806,
    "CoaMainId": 10,
    "UserId": 2,
    "Notes": "",
    "PRO_GLDefaultValue": [
            {
                "GLDefaultValueId": 0,
                "GLDefaultId": 0,
                "SegmentId": 16,
                "Alias": "ACT",
                "SegmentType": "DETAIL",
                "FunctionTypeId": 0,
                "Value": "&&&",
                "Mask": "&&&",
                "IsRequired": true,
                "LastModified": null,
                "IsCoaRequired": true
            },
            {
                "GLDefaultValueId": 0,
                "GLDefaultId": 0,
                "SegmentId": 17,
                "Alias": "ST",
                "SegmentType": "SET",
                "FunctionTypeId": 0,
                "Value": "&&",
                "Mask": "&&",
                "IsRequired": false,
                "LastModified": null,
                "IsCoaRequired": false
            }
        ]
}

***Response:***
{
    "$id": "1",
    "GLDefaultId": 1,
    "ProjectId": 1806,
    "CoaMainId": 10,
    "Notes": "",
    "PRO_GLDefaultValue": [
            {
                "$id": "2",
                "GLDefaultValueId": 1,
                "GLDefaultId": 1,
                "Alias": "ACT",
                "FunctionTypeId": 0,
                "Value": "&&&",
                "SegmentId": 16,
                "IsRequired": true,
                "ModifiedOn": "7/1/2017 4:48:06 PM",
                "ModifiedBy": 2,
                "PRO_GLDefault": {
                        "$ref": "1"
                    },
                "LastModified": null
            },
            {
                "$id": "3",
                "GLDefaultValueId": 2,
                "GLDefaultId": 1,
                "Alias": "ST",
                "FunctionTypeId": 0,
                "Value": "&&",
                "SegmentId": 17,
                "IsRequired": false,
                "ModifiedOn": "7/1/2017 4:48:06 PM",
                "ModifiedBy": 2,
                "PRO_GLDefault": {
                        "$ref": "1"
                    },
                "LastModified": null
            }
        ]
}

Please advise me how to overcome this

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Warning is just that, a warning, not an error, and expected if you have curly braces in your post

What is line 85, where the error is generated?

Comment: Line 85 is response where it's failing and i suspect warning causing for failure. I  have added  original request to the original post

Comment: You have not answered what is line 85

Comment: Line 85 is the request call  web_custom_request("PRO_GLDefault",
  "URL=https://{URL}/PayrollWebApi/V1/PRO_GLDefault?userId={UserId}",

Comment: The error is coming from your back end host, "{"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred."}"   As the administrator of the host about the source of the error.

Comment: I have figured it out where was the issue.The issue was with the API deployment.In new build deployment it's working as expected!

Answer (score 0):

See these two lines:

```
request_json_base=  "{\"GLDefaultId\":0,\"ProjectId\":{ContactProjectId},\"CoaMainId\":10,\"UserId\":{UserId},\"Notes\":\"\",\"PRO_GLDefaultValue\":[{\"GLDefaultValueId\":0,\"GLDefaultId\":0,\"SegmentId\":16,\"Alias\":\"ACT\",\"SegmentType\":\"DETAIL\",\"FunctionTypeId\":0,\"Value\":\"&&&\",\"Mask\":\"&&&\",\"IsRequired\":true,\"LastModified\":null,\"IsCoaRequired\":true},{\"GLDefaultValueId\":0,\"GLDefaultId\":0,\"SegmentId\":17,\"Alias\":\"ST\",\"SegmentType\":\"SET\",\"FunctionTypeId\":0,\"Value\":\"&&\",\"Mask\":\"&&\",\"IsRequired\":false,\"LastModified\":null,\"IsCoaRequired\":false}]}",

request_json = lr_eval_string(request_json_base);
```

They are not doing what you think they are doing. You are neither allocating space for this data ( see malloc() in combination with a char * variable), nor are you assigning the value to the variable correctly for the C language (see strcpy() )

Another reference here on Stackoverflow

[How to correctly assign a new string value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131319/how-to-correctly-assign-a-new-string-value)