# C - Using character arrays in struct

Tags: arrays, c, struct, char

I use `fscanf` to read an array of `char`s from a text file. I would like to add that string to a linked struct, however it gives me an error (`expression must be a modifiable value`). I'm using `struct`s for the first time, please help!

My struct:

```
typedef struct animals{
    char name_of_animal[51];
    struct animals *next;
} ANIMALS;
```

Later, the way I want to add a new element to this linked struct:

```
{
    char name_of_animal[51];
    /*
     * use fscanf to read into name_of_animal
     */

    ANIMALS* new_animal = (ANIMALS*) malloc(sizeof(ANIMALS)); 
    new_animal->name_of_animal = name_of_animal; 
    new_animal->next = (*pointer_to_pointer_to_beginning); 
    (*pointer_to_pointer_to_beginning) = new_animal; 
}
```

Comment: Please create a [mre]

Comment: Consider translating everything. It helps reading code parts you did not explicitly explain, i.e. all of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with `struct`s: you read a string into a `char[51]` (`name_of_animal`) and are trying to copy it into another `char[51]` (`new_animal->name_of_animal`) by using the assignment operator (`=`). You [can't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131319) and should instead use `strcpy` from `<string.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

*"I would like to add that string to a linked struct, however it gives me an error ("expression must be a modifiable value")"*

Regarding adding string to a linked struct, use a function to create a link and update the string member using a [string function](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/c-strings-string-functions/), rather than the `=` operator. Eg:

```
void createNode(struct zvierata** head_ref, char *new_data) 
{ 
    //allocate memory for new node
    struct zvierata *new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node)); 
   
    // copy data to member
    //new_node->meno_zvierata = new_data; // '=' does not work with strings
    strcpy(new_node->meno_zvierata,  new_data); 
   
    new_node->next = (*head_ref); 
   
    //finally move the head to point to the new node
    (*head_ref)    = new_node; 
}
```

*" I'm using structs for the first [time], please help!"*

Here are [several pages of tutorial on Linked Lists](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/?ref=lbp) (which is what you are using.)