# I'm learning about linked lists, but now every time I use this code, I get garbled characters in case1 and case3

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



struct LLNode
{

    char key[10];
    struct LLNode *next;

};


struct LLNode *creatNode(char val[10])
{

    struct LLNode*temp;
    temp=(struct LLNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct LLNode));
    temp->key[10]=val;
    temp->next=NULL;
    return (temp);

};

void push(char val[10], struct LLNode *head)
{
    struct LLNode *temp;
    temp = creatNode(val[10]);
    temp->next = head->next;
    head->next = temp;
}





int main()
{
    int cho,a=0;
    struct LLNode *head=NULL;
    struct LLNode *curr=NULL;

    head=creatNode('/0');
    curr=head;
    curr->next = creatNode("Jan");
    curr = curr->next;
    curr->next = creatNode("Feb");
    curr = curr->next;
    curr->next = creatNode("Mar");
    curr = curr->next;
    curr->next = creatNode("Apr");
    curr = curr->next;
    curr->next = creatNode("May");
    curr = curr->next;
    curr->next = creatNode("Jun");
    curr = curr->next;
    curr->next = creatNode("Jul");
    curr = curr->next;
    curr->next = creatNode("Aug");
    curr = curr->next;
    curr->next = creatNode("Sep");
    curr = curr->next;
    curr->next = creatNode("Oct");
    curr = curr->next;
    curr->next = creatNode("Nov");
    curr = curr->next;
    curr->next = creatNode("Dec");

    curr=head;


    printf("1. Create a new node in the linked list\n");

    printf("2. Search the month of 'May' in the linked list\n");

    printf("3. Display the content of each node\n");

    printf("4. Exit\n");

    printf("\n\nPlease enter the serial number of your choice:");

    scanf("%d",&cho);

    switch(cho)
    {

    case 1:
        push ("newnode", head);
        printf("head->next->key = %s\n",head->next->key) ;
        printf("the new node is insert successfully");
        break;

    case 2:
        curr=head;
        while(a==0)
        {

            if(curr->key[10]="May")a=1;

            else curr=curr->next;

        }
        curr=head;
        if(a==1) printf("\n'May'is in the list.\n");

        else printf("\n'May'is not in the list.\n");
        break;



    case 3:
        curr=head;
        while(curr)
        {



            printf("%s  ",curr->key);

        curr=curr->next;

        }

        break;


    case 4:
        printf("You are exiting");
        break;



    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm learning about linked lists, but now every time I use this code, I get garbled in the string output in case1 and case3.

The purpose of this code is to implement the tasks in the image(In the link)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQd6a.png)
The first time I used it, I found that I was asked to add a few more statements, so I copied some nonsense here
The first time I used it, I found that I was asked to add a few more statements, so I copied some nonsense here
The first time I used it, I found that I was asked to add a few more statements, so I copied some nonsense here
The first time I used it, I found that I was asked to add a few more statements, so I copied some nonsense here

Comment: Doesn't the compiler complain about the assignment `temp->key[10]=val`? That's not how you copy an array. Also, `creatNode(val[10])` is wrong. As is `creatNode('/0')`. I think you need to spend a little more time with your text-books to learn more about strings, arrays and pointers.

Comment: Please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and don't post noise just to work around the system asking you formulate a complete question.

Answer (score 0):

In case 2, please note that you have not checked to determine if `curr` is `NULL`. If `"May"` is not found, this will happily loop until `curr` is `NULL` and then you'll attempt to access a member field on `NULL`, causing an error.

In case 1 you similarly have to checked that `head->next` is or is not `NULL`.

I suggest in case 2 you replace your while loop with something like:

Also in case 2 you have a couple of errors:

> ```
> if(curr->key[10]="May")a=1;
> ```

1. You are assigning to `curr->key[10]`.
2. You are assigning a char pointer to a char.
3. `key` only holds ten chars. Indexing starts at `0`, so `10` is out of bounds.
4. If you're attempting to copy a string, string copying in C doesn't work that way.

Your confusion about C string handling and assigning to arrays appears in other locations in your code.

[Recommended reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131319/how-can-i-correctly-assign-a-new-string-value) via [the C tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info).